# Using SUMIF based on mulitple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need some assistance using SUMIF.  Trying to sum financial data in a column (Col D -4th column below) based on a dates in Col B (2nd column) that can be variable, but also need to exclude certain financial data if Col C (3rd column) has a date is populated.

```
Row 1 - Start Date: 06/01/22
Row 2 - End Date:   06/30/22
Row 3 - App     Forecast        Actual      Dollars   Comments
Row 4 - A       06/15/22                    $10K      Include in calculation
Row 5 - B       06/27/22                    $10K      Include in calculation
Row 6 - C       06/22/22        05/27/22    $10K      Exclude in calculation
Row 7 - D       07/07/22                    $10K      Exclude in calculation
```

Tried using sumif but can only get it to sum if the date range of 2nd column is within the start and end date.  I've used the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS(D4:S7,B4:B7,">="&$A$2,B4:B7,"<="&$B$2)
```

to get data to sum to $30K, but can't get it to exclude the $10K for the "C" application.

Comment: why `D4:S7` shouldn't that be just `D4:D7`?

Comment: Try `=SUMIFS(D4:D7,B4:B7,">="&$A$2,B4:B7,"<="&$B$2,C4:C7,">0")`  not sure if it will work, depends on if the blanks are true blanks or not.

Comment: You are trying to sum the Dollars columns? Did you format your number that way, or is that text? If text, `SUMIFS()` (or any other value based formula) will NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a third `IF` test:  `C4:C7,"="&""`

So your formula would then be:

```
=SUMIFS(D4:S7,B4:B7,">="&$A$2,B4:B7,"<="&$B$2,C4:C7,"="&"")
```

Of course, as `Scott Craner` says, fix your "S for D" typo. And fix your Start Date/End Date cell addresses problem:  Looks like you intended `$B$1` not `$A$2`.

And then all is good.

It's not laziness or over-formality that has that last clause's condition a joining of two strings instead of just the simpler single string. It just won't work for me in a half dozen variations on how to enter it and have the condition work. So I just did the simple splitting of it like the other two conditions, the comparator in the first half ("=") and the thing to compare to in the second half ("").

But it does have the advantage of pattern-matching the other two conditions which should make understanding the formula and maintaining it a year from now somewhat easier.